# css3 html5 - want to be able to display images and have left/right arrows to scroll through to next ones

Tags: html, css, animation

Is there a way using just css3 and html5 code to display an image central on the page and have arrows on right and left sides as overlays that when clicked on will transition to the next image?

I have approximately 20 photos I would like to scroll through.  I see lots of jquery and javascript out there to achieve this, but wonder if it can be done just by using css3/html5 code.

Here is a website that does something similar with small images then click on them to get larger ones, but I don't need all that detail, just when you do click on the larger images I want to have that effect of being able to scroll through photos using the arrows.

Eg: http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/11/hovering-gallery-css3-jquery/demo.php

Kind regards,
Bill

Comment: There is a **View the original tutorial »** link - have you tried looking at that? Yes, it is possible to do it using just CSS (checkbox hack), but it would be a lot cleaner to let JavaScript do the switching. You might also want to take a look at this http://dabblet.com/gist/3796554

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 transitions can be used for the carousel animation and I would recommend using them instead of jQuery `.animate()` as they perform better.

## CSS Transition

```
.carousel { transition: all cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.175, 1); }
```

Then by changing the margin (left or right depending on the direction) in CSS this will trigger the transition.

```
.carousel { margin-left: -100%; }
```

Carousels do still generally need a bit of JavaScript to complete their functionality, whether it be the click events or to enable auto scrolling etc.

The :target selector is available to us, so we could potentially do something on click.

## Target Example

> ### HTML
>
> ```
> <a href="#" class="left">Prev</a>
> <ul class="carousel">
>     <li>Slide 1</li>
>     <li>Slide 2</li>
> </ul>
> <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>
> ```
>
> ### CSS
>
> ```
> .left:target ~ .carousel{
>     margin-left: 100%;
> }
> ```

There is one example of a carousel that uses no JavaScript which can be found here

[Responsive CSS3 Slider Without Javascript](http://csscience.com/responsiveslidercss3/)

It's quite a clever approach that uses radio buttons to handle the click event.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out Bootstrap's carousel, it's exactly what you are looking for.

And here is how you would use it, provided that you included Bootstrap's JavaScript file, and linked your page to Bootstrap's stylesheet:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
        <img src="image1.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="image2.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="image3.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="carousel-caption"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

It comes with arrows, and indicators (you can remove them if you have a lot of pictures) and left/right navigation icons.

You can also make it cycle through the pictures automatically every X seconds, that you can define the following way:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000 /* 2 seconds */
})
```